# SharePoint licensing with webservices

Tags: 2010, web-services, licensing

Suppose, I consume SharePoint services using web services in my enterprise. All the web services connections are made using a single service account.

How do I derive the named user licenses required in this case ? Will it be counted as single user or n users which ultimately access the client application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it to be the latter, as the n people will be the ones hitting and accessing the content.  Licensing is a tricky beast, its best to talk with your local Microsoft reps or with the company you've acquired SharePoint through.